# Subtract two input values in PHP and update mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a Payment Form that contains some fields about the payment..

There are two input fields:

1)Available in Stock
2) Quantity

(Available in Stock) field value will be retrieved from the database, but (Quantity) field value will be entered by the user.

**My question is**: how do I subtract the the entered value (in Quantity field) from the (Available in Stock) value? and then Update the (Available in Stock) column in database with the new result.

Comment: Basic sql: `update youtable set available=available-$quantity, quantity=$quantity where ...`

Comment: I tried to do a javascript function but i faced a problem when i tried to make a query to update the database since javascript is a clint side :(

Comment: post your complete code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a basic `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET AvailQuantity=AvailQuantity-$Quantity 
WHERE productId=$productID
```

Comment: @user3557264: Can you show the attempt with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET avacol=avacol-'$quantity' 
WHERE //your condition here//
```